# Change of Coordinates and Topological Equivalence of ODE

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-topology, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Let 
\begin{align}
\dot x = f(x) \tag{1}
\end{align}
be an ODE where $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth. Let us also define the map $M:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ that maps $x\mapsto y$ defined as 
\begin{align}
M(x)=\{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} : y_i = x_i - x_n, \forall i \in \{1,...,n-1\} \}.
\end{align}
Suppose we perform a change of coordinates from $x$ to $y$.
Now, what is the relationship between the original ODE (1) and the new ODE
\begin{align}
\dot y = g(y) \tag{2}
\end{align}
which is in a lower dimension?
Any idea/response is greatly appreciated!

> My work: I tried to prove that the two systems (1) and (2) are topologically equivalent. The map $M$ is smooth. However, I am not sure if I can define an inverse for $M$. For instance, we can define
>   \begin{align}
> M^{-1}(y)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_i = y_i, \forall i \in \{1,...,n-1\}, x_n = 0 \}.
> \end{align}
>   Can we say that this "defined" inverse function is smooth? If yes, can we conclude that the restriction of $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times\{0\}$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: In general, $g=DM(M^{-1}(y))f(M^{-1}(y))$, where $DM$ is the Jacobian of $M$.